# Doctrine: How to remove part of a where clause from select query inside listener (preDqlSelect)?

Tags: php, doctrine, listener, behavior

My listener is part of a behavior, that should remove all is_published checks in the where clause of any called select query. Adding a part to a clause is really easy, but how to remove one.

There are some functions like `Doctrine_Query->removeDqlQueryPart('where')`, 
but that removes the complete where clause, while I only need the `'is_published = ?'` part to be removed.

However I could handle this manually somehow, with regex or something. But the tricky part is, how to remove the parameter represented by the '?' from the corresponding parameters array (retrievable by `Doctrine_Query->getRawParams()`).

So I ask, is there a clean way to transform this kind of query:
`...FROM Video v WHERE v.is_published = ? AND v.start_date < ? AND v.end_date > ?`

to this stripped one and without messing up the params represented by the question marks:
`...FROM Video v WHERE v.start_date < ? AND v.end_date > ?`

This is of course just a simple example, my queries are a bit more complex.
Unfortunately I'm stuck with doctrine 1.0.x because of the symfony framework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling `$query->getDqlPart('where')` will return an `array` of the parts of the where clause as they were added via the `where()`, `andWhere()`, etc functions. So you can use that to find and remove the part you want.

Then you have to deal with the params. While cycling through the where parts you would need to find all ? and count them and remember the numbers for any of the ones you remove and then call `$params = $query->getParams();` and the where clause parameters will be in `$params['where']` so you can remove them from there and then call `$query->setParams($params);`

Answer (score 9):

Based Joshua Coady Answer

```
    $qb = <query builder>;
    $qb_where_part = $qb->getDqlPart('where')->getParts();
    $qb->resetDQLPart('where');
    // we know by dumping that it is an and operator in our case, generic way shoud take op in account
    //var_dump($qb->getDqlPart('where'));
    foreach ($qb_where_part as $where_clause) {
        if ('o.date > :date_debut' === $where_clause) continue;
        $qb->andWhere($where_clause);
    }
    $params = $qb->getParameters();
    $new_date_fin = null;
    foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
        if ($param->getName() === 'date_debut') {
            $new_date_fin = $param->getValue();
            $params->remove($key);
        }
        if ($param->getName() === 'date_fin' && $new_date_fin) {
            $param->setValue($new_date_fin);
            //var_dump($param->getValue());
        }
    }
    $qb->setParameters($params);
    var_dump($qb->getParameters());
    var_dump($qb->getDqlPart('where'));
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Examples go a long way :)

Comment: This solution works for the "where" clause but not for example the "groupBy" clause : In this case the getParts() should be replaced by: ... $qb_group_by_part = $qb->getDqlPart('groupBy'); $qb_group_by_part = isset($qb_group_by_part["parts"]) ? $qb_group_by_part["parts"] : array(); ..